# Some problems with full-screen resolutions and glfw

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

Ive been having some problems with making a full-screen item in glfw (C). From the docs they say to execute `glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "glfw-application-name", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL)` to create a full-screen application. This does work however my resolution is changed to a significantly lower one upon closing the application. Any ideas why this happens?

- OS: Linux Arch 64bit
- Lib: glfw3
- Default screen resolution: 1920x1080
- Language: C
- Referenced Documentation Page: https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_full_screen

**Some sample code**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        printf("Unable to initialize GLFW\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // GLoptions //

    // Make a fullscreen unresizeable window that is always on the top of the screen //
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FLOATING, GLFW_TRUE); // Always on top
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_MAXIMIZED, GLFW_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_REFRESH_RATE, 60); // Max 60 fps
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE);
    // Make a fullscreen unresizeable window that is always on the top of the screen //
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 0); // No antialiasing

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); // OPENGL 3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // GLoptions //

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "glfw", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to create window!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: A look here seems to indicate that you need to call `glfwTerminate();` at the end of your program: https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html

Comment: ah such a silly mistake my bad

Comment: upon setting ```glfwTerminate()``` to a key bind and executing it the error still occurs even thought I have verified that the function is being executed.

Comment: you are requesting a 640x480 fullscreen resolution, and that is what you get. There is absolutely no point in doing what you are doing, besides trying to annoy users. Even if you really need a 640x480 resolution internally, it would been scaled to the display resolution for fullscreen anyway, so you can better do that _yourself_ instead of tweaking the user's resolution.

Comment: I'll do that thank you